# How to update db's column name wihout creating a new db? (Android Studio ,SQLite)

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio

I changed one of the column's name in my db and when I run my app I get this error :

```
5 10449-10449/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.liavbapps.mascoret, PID: 10449
                                               android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: TarrifHolyDay (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE MySettings SET TarrifHolyDay=?
```

I know that happens beacuse it try to update a column that doesnt exist in my current db.
If I will open a new db it will contain the new column name , but I lose my data.
 My question is how can I update my current db's column name, in oreder to keep my data ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the table, check `ALTER TALBE SQL` command :

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php

Take a look of **MODIFY COLUMN IN TABLE** section.

Comment: you can post link ? how can I execute that in android studio?

Comment: Yep, check "MODIFY COLUMN IN TABLE" in this link: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php

Comment: I don't know any android studio feature that can execute this commad independently, so I guess you need to run it once at the sql initialization (and after wards remove it) or you can alllways pull the db file from the device, update it on your pc and push it back